# shifting arrays in a for loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Sometimes the simplest things become the most confusing.

```js
let arr = ['x', 'y', 'z'];

for(let i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
    let prop = arr.shift();
    console.log(prop); 
    console.log(arr, `${i} <= ${arr.length}`);
}
```

it prints out

```
x
[ 'y', 'z' ] '0 <= 2'
y
[ 'z' ] '1 <= 1'
```

How come 'z' doesn't show up with this code as part of the console.log(prop)?

Comment: Because you're adjusting the length of the array with every `shift`.

Comment: by z, shouldn't the length be 1 with i being 1, 1 <= 1?

Comment: But by then `i` is 2.

Answer (score 4):

You short the array by shifting and use an index with is incrementing for every loop.

The result is it loops only twice, one for element one and two, and one for element three.

At the end, you got index `2`, but the length of the array is `1`.

```js
let arr = ['x', 'y', 'z'];

for(let i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
    let prop = arr.shift();
    console.log(prop); 
    console.log(arr, `${i} <= ${arr.length}`);
}
```

A better approach by using only the shiftend element and checking only the length of the array.

```js
let arr = ['x', 'y', 'z'],
    i = 0;

while (arr.length) {
    let prop = arr.shift();
    console.log(prop); 
    console.log(arr, `${++i} < ${arr.length}`);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You adjust the length of the array with every `shift` call, and the boundary check inside your `for`-loop tests against that.

You can cache the length in another variable to demonstrate:

```js
let arr = ['x', 'y', 'z'];
let len = arr.length;

for(let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    let prop = arr.shift();
    console.log(prop); 
    console.log(arr, `${i} <= ${arr.length}`);
}
```

This technique was once recommended by some for performance reasons; that is rarely necessary any more.  But if your loop is changing the array, it might still be important.

---

Why this doesn't work as is:

1. set `arr` to ['x', 'y', 'z']
2. set `i` to 0
3. test `i <= arr.length`, true since 0 <= 3
4. do loop body, `prop` is `'x'`, `arr` is `['y', 'z']`
5. perform `i++`, now `i` is 1
6. test `i < arr.length`, true since 1 <= 2
7. do loop body, `prop` is `'y'`, `arr` is `['z']`
8. perform `i++`, now `i` is 2
9. test `i < arr.length`, false since 2 > 1
10. completed

Answer (score 1):

`z` is not getting printed because the value of `i` becomes greater then the `length` of array when it reaches `z`, which is `1`. the loop wont run further as `i<array.length` is violated. `i` will be 2 and length will be 1

You can use a while loop like this

```js
let arr = ['x', 'y', 'z'];
let i=0;
var x=arr.length;
while(i<x) {
    let prop = arr.shift();
    console.log(prop); 
    if(i<=arr.length)
    console.log(arr, `${i} <= ${arr.length}`);
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because at the end of the second loop, the array is `['z']`, `i` is `1`, and `arr.length` is `1` as well. However, before the next iteration, `i` is incremented to `2` which is greater than `arr.length = 1`, which effectively stops the loop.

Answer (score 1):

`Array.prototype.shift` mutates an array by both removing the first element **and** decreasing its `length` property.

Therefore, before you get to the 3rd element (`z`), `arr`'s length is `1`. However, `i` is `2`. Your for loop exits because `2 > 1`; thus, you don't see `z` logged to the console.

Answer (score 1):

Your changing the `length` every time you do an array `shift`

```js
let arr = ['x', 'y', 'z'];

for (let i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
  let prop = arr.shift();
  console.log(prop);
  console.log(arr, `${i} <= ${arr.length}`);
}
```